# “[Errno 13] Permission denied” in mailman mailing lists after upgrade to 2.1.29-6 in Fedora 30

Tags: python

I've seen several suggestions to fix this including [one here on SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/howto-fix-errno-13-permission-denied-in-mailman-mailing-lists).

Does mailman 2.1 now need to run as the same user as Apache runs? In our case `httpd` runs as the user ‘`apache`’ and mailman runs as ‘`mailman`’. I reinstalled mailman and no difference. I’ve seen this error referenced several time and to run `check_perms` which I did.

```
/usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms
/usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailman-update-cfg bad group (has: root, expected mailman)
Problems found: 1
Re-run as mailman (or root) with -f flag to fix

ls -l /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailman-update-cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 436 Feb 12 06:54 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailman-update-cfg

chown mailman:mailman /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailman-update-cfg
/usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms
No problems found


systemctl status mailman
● mailman.service - GNU Mailing List Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mailman.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-07-18 16:18:41 EDT; 3 days ago
Main PID: 20380 (mailmanctl)
 Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 131.2M
CGroup: /system.slice/mailman.service
        ├─20380 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailmanctl -s start
        ├─20381 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=ArchRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20382 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=BounceRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20383 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=CommandRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20384 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=IncomingRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20385 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=NewsRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20386 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=OutgoingRunner:0:1 -s
        ├─20387 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=VirginRunner:0:1 -s
        └─20388 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=RetryRunner:0:1 -s
Jul 18 16:18:41 ourhost.edu systemd[1]: Starting GNU Mailing List Manager...
Jul 18 16:18:41 ourhost.edu mailmanctl[20379]: Starting Mailman's master qrunner.
Jul 18 16:18:41 ourhost.edu systemd[1]: Started GNU Mailing List Manager.


ls -l /var/lib/mailman/lists/book/
total 24
-rw-rw---- 1 mailman mailman 5593 Jul 22 09:00 config.pck
-rw-rw---- 1 mailman mailman 5593 Jul 21 12:00 config.pck.last
-rw-rw---- 1 mailman mailman  131 Oct 12  2018 pending.pck
-rw-rw---- 1 apache  mailman   20 Oct 13  2018 request.pck
```

After a reinstall, the actual log file is noted as having a permission problem:

```
    ls -l  /var/log/mailman/error
    -rw-rw---- 1 mailman mailman 37997 Jul 22 10:57 /var/log/mailman/error

[----- Mailman Version: 2.1.29 -----]
[----- Traceback ------]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/mailman/scripts/driver", line 85, in run_main
 immediate=1)
File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Logging/StampedLogger.py", line 52, in __init__
 Logger.__init__(self, category, nofail, immediate)
File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Logging/Logger.py", line 50, in __init__
 self.__get_f()
File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Logging/Logger.py", line 68, in __get_f
 1)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py", line 898, in open
 file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/mailman/error'
[----- Python Information -----]
sys.version     = 2.7.16 (default, Apr 30 2019, 15:54:43) 
[GCC 9.0.1 20190312 (Red Hat 9.0.1-0.10)]
sys.executable  = /usr/bin/python2
sys.prefix      = /usr
sys.exec_prefix = /usr
sys.path        = ['/usr/lib/mailman/pythonlib', '/usr/lib/mailman', '/usr/lib/mailman/scripts', '/usr/lib/mailman', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
sys.platform    = linux2
     PYTHONPATH: /usr/lib/mailman
     REMOTE_PORT: 60557
     REQUEST_SCHEME: https
     SCRIPT_NAME: /mailman/listinfo
     REQUEST_METHOD: GET
     SERVER_PORT: 443
     SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
     QUERY_STRING: 
     REQUEST_URI: /mailman/listinfo
     DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
```

Then I `chmod 755` to the log file then I see this error:

```
admin(24082): [----- Mailman Version: 2.1.29 -----] 
admin(24082): [----- Traceback ------] 
admin(24082): Traceback (most recent call last):
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/scripts/driver", line 117, in run_main
admin(24082):     main()
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/listinfo.py", line 44, in main
admin(24082):     listinfo_overview()
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/listinfo.py", line 104, in listinfo_overview
admin(24082):     mlist = MailList.MailList(name, lock=0)
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 133, in __init__
admin(24082):     self.Load()
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 692, in Load
admin(24082):     dict, e = self.__load(file)
admin(24082):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 655, in __load
admin(24082):     fp = open(dbfile)
admin(24082): IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mailman/lists/book/config.pck'
admin(24082): [----- Python Information -----] 
admin(24082): sys.version     =   2.7.16 (default, Apr 30 2019, 15:54:43) 
[GCC 9.0.1 20190312 (Red Hat 9.0.1-0.10)] 
admin(24082): sys.executable  =   /usr/bin/python2 
admin(24082): sys.prefix      =   /usr
```

Based on the linked thread I tried running  `chown -hR mailman:mailman ./*` at `/var/lib/mailman/` to no avail.

```
ps -elf | grep -i mailman
1 S mailman   2392     1  0  80   0 - 66788 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailmanctl -s start
0 S mailman   2393  2392  0  80   0 - 59169 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=ArchRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2394  2392  0  80   0 - 59146 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=BounceRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2395  2392  0  80   0 - 59139 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=CommandRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2396  2392  0  80   0 - 59146 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=IncomingRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2397  2392  0  80   0 - 59172 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=NewsRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2398  2392  0  80   0 - 59137 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=OutgoingRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2399  2392  0  80   0 - 59138 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=VirginRunner:0:1 -s
0 S mailman   2400  2392  0  80   0 - 59137 -      14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=RetryRunner:0:1 -s



systemctl status mailman
● mailman.service - GNU Mailing List Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mailman.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-07-22 14:36:23 EDT; 56min ago
  Process: 2386 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailman-update-cfg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2387 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m644 -o root -g root /usr/lib/mailman/cron/crontab.in /etc/cron.d/mailman (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2388 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /var/log/mailman/error (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2389 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mailman:mailman /var/log/mailman/error (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2390 ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 666 /var/log/mailman/error (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2391 ExecStart=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailmanctl -s start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2392 (mailmanctl)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 128.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mailman.service
           ├─2392 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailmanctl -s start
           ├─2393 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=ArchRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2394 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=BounceRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2395 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=CommandRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2396 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=IncomingRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2397 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=NewsRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2398 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=OutgoingRunner:0:1 -s
           ├─2399 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=VirginRunner:0:1 -s
           └─2400 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=RetryRunner:0:1 -s

Jul 22 14:36:22 systemd[1]: Starting GNU Mailing List Manager...
Jul 22 14:36:23 mailmanctl[2391]: Starting Mailman's master qrunner.
Jul 22 14:36:23 systemd[1]: Started GNU Mailing List Manager.
```

Edit: do these logs help?

```
Jul 24 16:38:28 2019 admin(3609): @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
admin(3609): [----- Mailman Version: 2.1.29 -----] 
admin(3609): [----- Traceback ------] 
admin(3609): Traceback (most recent call last):
admin(3609):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/scripts/driver", line 117, in run_main
admin(3609):     main()
admin(3609):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admindb.py", line 345, in main
admin(3609):     mlist.Save()
admin(3609):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 613, in Save
admin(3609):     self.__save(dict)
admin(3609):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/MailList.py", line 590, in __save
admin(3609):     os.link(fname, fname_last)
admin(3609): OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
admin(3609): [----- Python Information -----] 
admin(3609): sys.version     =   2.7.16 (default, Apr 30 2019, 15:54:43) 
[GCC 9.0.1 20190312 (Red Hat 9.0.1-0.10)] 
admin(3609): sys.executable  =   /usr/bin/python2 
admin(3609): sys.prefix      =   /usr 
admin(3609): sys.exec_prefix =   /usr 
admin(3609): sys.path        =   ['/usr/lib/mailman/pythonlib', '/usr/lib/mailman', '/usr/lib/mailman/scripts', '/usr/lib/mailman', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'] 
admin(3609): sys.platform    =   linux2 
admin(3609): [----- Environment Variables -----] 
admin(3609):    CONTENT_LENGTH: 38 
admin(3609):    HTTPS: on 
admin(3609):    HTTP_COOKIE:  
admin(3609):    SERVER_NAME: ourdomain 
admin(3609):    SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1 
admin(3609):    PYTHONPATH: /usr/lib/mailman 
admin(3609):    REMOTE_ADDR: myip 
admin(3609):    REQUEST_SCHEME: https 
admin(3609):    SCRIPT_NAME: /mailman/admindb 
admin(3609):    REQUEST_METHOD: POST 
admin(3609):    SERVER_PORT: 443 
admin(3609):    HTTP_HOST: ourdomain 
admin(3609):    PATH_INFO: /mailman 
admin(3609):    CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
admin(3609):    REMOTE_PORT: 57350 
admin(3609):    QUERY_STRING:  
admin(3609):    REQUEST_URI: /mailman/admindb/mailman 
admin(3609):    DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
```

Comment: Did you intend to be running mailman 2 instead of mailman3? I'm not sure the old version is getting much attention anymore.

Comment: We aren't tied to it. Is there a simple upgrade path, i.e., tutorial?

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.mailman3.org/en/latest/upgrade-3.2.html) mention rebuilding an index, but that's about all I can find. Personally I've only done a new install so I'm not a 100% sure on it.

Comment: I added some new logs after making sure permissions were updated to run as user:mailman.

Comment: It sure looks like a plain old permissions problem. Since you've apparently disabled SELinux, that isn't likely to be it. Check that the user and group of the mailman service and the mailman's CGI scripts are correct.

Comment: Not sure if it's really a bug but I created https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1733359. I can't figure out how to get the service to use the effective group mailman, currently it's apache, and that's the cause of the problem. Is there anything I can out in the mailman.service file?